# PHP: Determinar si $array_1['elemento_i'] se encuentra en $array2, de estructura $array['indices']['elementos']

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente código, que adelanto que no funciona, y que procede de una llamada a mi base de datos MYSQL:

```
while($filas[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados));

array_pop($filas);

$json = array();    

foreach($filas as $clave => $fila) 
{
    $cuarteto = array("nombre_autor" => $fila['nombre_autor'], "titulo_cancion" => $fila['titulo_cancion'], "titulo_disco" => $fila['titulo_disco'], "ano" => $fila['ano']);

    if(count($filas) > 5)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($json); $i++) 
        { 
            if($cuarteto["nombre_autor"] == $json[$i]["nombre_autor"]) break;
            else array_push($json, $cuarteto);
        }
    }  
    else array_push($json, $cuarteto);

    if(count($json) > 4) break;
}
```

Lo que pretendo es que el array numérico `$json` contenga 5 arrays asociativos `$cuarteto` diferentes y que además nunca se repita el `nombre_autor` en ellos.

Es decir, la base de datos contiene canciones, que obviamente no se repiten, son únicas, pero en ocasiones dos o más canciones pertenecen al mismo autor; por tanto, si a `$json` se añade un `$cuarteto` con `nombre_autor = 'Radiohead'`, aunque mediante el `foreach` se formen nuevos `$cuarteto` con `nombre_autor = 'Radiohead'`, estos han de ser obviados y no incluidos en `$json`.

Esto vendría controlado por:

```
if(count($filas) > 5)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($json); $i++) 
    { 
        if($cuarteto["nombre_autor"] == $json[$i]["nombre_autor"]) break;
        else array_push($json, $cuarteto);
    }
}
```

La razón de hacer un recuento de `$filas` es porque si hay muy pocos resultados quiero incluirlos todos aunque se repitan, con el objetivo de intentar llegar a 5; soy consciente de que el recuento no es muy fiable, porque si hay 6 resultados pero pertenecen sólo a 2 autores diferentes, `$json` sólo incluiría 2 registros, pero la probabilidad de que ocurra eso es baja y ya intentaré lidiar con las excepciones una vez haya resuelto el problema que nos ocupa ahora.

Con mi código actual, si `count($filas) > 5`, `$json` acaba vacío, pero incluso si funcionase se repetirían registros en cuanto el `nombre_autor` repetido no ocupase la posición `$i = 0`, ¿no?

Es un asunto un tanto complicado de detallar, comentadme si necesitáis explicaciones adicionales o más código.

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Deberías resolver esto a nivel de la consulta en la BD y no por PHP. No es óptimo traer datos de cualquier manera para luego desecharlos. No por casualidad existen en las BD funciones de agrupación y demás. Delegar esto en el lenguaje de programación es un error de diseño que a veces tiene consecuencias muy graves.

Comment: El asunto es que en ocasiones no quiero desecharlos, cuando `count($filas)` no es mayor que 5.

Comment: No me refiero sólo a eso, sino también a lo que dices sobre `Radiohead`, ¿por qué mejor no agrupas? Y en cuanto a lo de mayor que `5` o no, también habría que verlo y quizá replantear la lógica. Lo que pasa es que también la pregunta no está planteada con demasiada claridad, eso dificulta entender el contexto y poder sugerirte mejoras con más certeza.